# Indexing and Partition on same column

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, partition

Can we have partition on date column like :

> PARTITION BY RANGE( TO_DAYS(date_time) ) (

and Indexing on the same column based on Hour of the day like:

> CREATE INDEX *index_name* ON *tabel_name* (HOUR(date_time));

Partition is required so that later data can be deleted easily by simply dropping the partition.
Indexing we are trying to speed up the query based on date_time column (since for a single day too there would be millions of rows).

Is it the correct way and how will it behave? Also any other better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe.

The partitioning is excellent for purging old data, but does not benefit most queries.  An index on hour is unlikely to ever be used.  Let's see the queries.

What would a typical `SELECT` be?  If it is filtering on some other column, then indexing by hour is useless.  If you are filtering only on hour, or any datetime type value, then having the datetime as the *first* column in a non-partitioned table is optimal.  (And `PARTITIONing` is beneficial only for purging 'old' data.)

Be aware that an index with values 0..23 is useful only for lookups that specify a value between 0 and 23.  If you want to find a row that is sometime during the noon hour of a particular day:

```
WHERE dt >= '2020-01-02 12:00:00'
  AND dt  < '2020-01-02 12:00:00' + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

is the most practical and efficient way.  And that requires an index with `dt`, not a standalone hour index.

More on the purging:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint